# Getting only date from iso string in pouchDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pouchdb

In my reactJS app, I currently save createdAt by using `new Date()` and when I retrieve this column I get a full ISO string.

I want to modify this so that I can only return the date in MM-DD-YYYY format. Here's my current code:

```
getMax = () => {

    this.state.caloriesDB.db.createIndex({
      index: {
        fields: ['_id','caloriesBurned', 'createdAt']
      }
    }).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.setMax();

   }).catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  setMax = () => {
    this.state.caloriesDB.db.find({
      selector: {
        $and: [
          {_id: {"$gte": null}},
          {caloriesBurned: {$exists: true}},
          {createdAt: {$exists: true}}
        ]
      },
      fields: ['caloriesBurned', 'createdAt'],
      sort: [{'_id':'desc'}],
      limit: 7
    })
```

In my `setMax` function where I get the field `createdAt`, how can I pull out only the formatted date from that string to show on the front end?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can format the dates using something like date-fns library (https://date-fns.org/v2.11.1/docs/format). So when you fetch the data from pouchdb you can do something like this when trying to display it format(new Date(createdAt), 'MM-dd-yyyy')

Comment: @needsleep I think that makes sense, as long as I"m only displaying that column and not just using the whole object of elements. Slightly off-topic, but do you know of a good way to store just a date into pouchdb? The way I do it now saves as ISO but what's a good way that I can just save it as the date, rather than the timestamp

Comment: Actually I usually save dates as timestamp eg 1585423784327(using new Date(),getTime()), cause formatting the date is usually performed later on the UI with libraries like momentjs or date-fns. But I also seen people save it as "2020-3-28" as you have it I suppose